# Change background image to multiple divs from a specific parent div

Tags: jquery

I need help with a DIV background issue.
I want to create a price table script with, lets say, 6 columns:

```
<div id="col1">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="first_line"></div>
  <div class="second_line"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
<div id="col2">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="first_line"></div>
  <div class="second_line"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
.
.
.
.
<div id="col6">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="first_line"></div>
  <div class="second_line"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
```

I want to change the background image to all divs with a hovered parent.
If I hover `div "col6"`, I want all divs from it to change background image.
Note that I use the same classes for all columns and I need to change only the one from main div that is hovered.

I have found this code snippet but I don't know how to adapt it to work in my situation (as my javascript knowledge is very low):

```
 $(function() {
    $('.parent').hover( function(){
       $(this).children("div").css('background-color', 'gray');
    },
     function(){
       $(this).children("div").css('background-color', 'red');
    });
 });
```

Thank you and hope all makes sense

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/4g2Kj/

Answer (score 2):

As your container elements don't have class attributes, you can use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
$(function() {
    $('div[id^=col]').hover(function() {
         $(this).children("div").css('background-image', 'url("heaven.png")');
    }, function() {
         $(this).children("div").css('background-image', 'url("hell.png")');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why JavaScript when you can do it with CSS?

Comment: @MicheleBertoli I have just suggested a solution for the question, yes, we can also use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS, like this:

```
#col6:hover div
{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Please, see the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nTAzk/

Then you can add a class to all the parents (like .parent-class) and do it once for each column.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to close properly your "div" element:

```
<div id="col6">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="first_line"></div>
  <div class="second_line"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div> <-- HERE NEED TO BE "</div>"
```

Second, you can add a class (so, if you change `col[N]` to `foo[N]` you don't need to edit any script.

```
<div id="col1" class="sample-class">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="first_line"></div>
  <div class="second_line"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
<div id="col2" class="sample-class">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="first_line"></div>
  <div class="second_line"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Third, use the follow code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sample-class').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('div').css('backgroundColor', 'gray');
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('div').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4g2Kj/

Comment: Hi guy's and thanks for fast replay. I think i made a mistake in explaining corect my problem. My clases header, first_line, second_line and footer have a background image. So what i need actualy is when i hover the main div with ID "col1" is to change to all children divs clases to header_hover, second_line_hover, .... Your example above works perfect with color background but I need actualy to change the class as each class has other image as background. Thank you again for your time and please excuse my mistake in explication. best regards